# Task Scheduling not executing a Powershell script that can be manually run through Task Scheduler (Windows10)

Tags: powershell, events, scheduled-tasks, windows-10

Trying to follow this guidelines https://github.com/vstarostenko/dv8p_wifi_issue_fix/blob/master/README.md I have now a Powershell script that works, but that is not triggered with event 507.

- The script works if manually run through Task Scheduler (in windows 10) (shown by history record and because I have an alert in the script that displays a message)
- The 507 event is shown in the event-viewer when it moves back from standby
- And the marked options in the Task appear to be correct (see below)
- *But the script doesn't run in response to the event

Any idea?

[image: screenshots of Task Scheduler]

Comment: Check if the task runs at all, by enabing task scheduler logging. If yes, you have to check Powershell scripting policy if that prevents Powershell from launching the script.

Comment: The task doesn't run (if you mean by activating and looking at the logs). It does appear there if I manually check "Run" in the Task Scheduling, but otherwise it never appears there. I also assume that if it works by pressing "Run" it means that the policy is correct (I run Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned in Powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running the task not based on the event but on a particular minute, and it worked.

Then I tried to do the same event trigger, but then something changed. I did exactly the same but in the "Source" input, except saying Kernel-power, it now says Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power, having selected the same.

And now it works.

My assumption, I updated 2 days ago the system and it downloaded several critical files (I didn't pay attention, but it sounded to me to the first windows10 pseudo-service-package that I read few days ago). I guess that they corrected the bug(?), but that it still persisted until I have re-done the Trigger again.

Anyway, now it works :)